# Python Scapy Recursive DNS Query - Script from a Book

Tags: python, scapy

I am reading a Python book and it has a tutorial to install and use *scapy*. One of the scripts to try is a "recursive DNS query of www.oreilly.com using Caltech University's public DNS server". I am not sure why anyone would want to do this for an useful reason either. If someone could also explain why this is useful that would be awesome. :D

I start *scapy* from the `bin` directory, `./bin/scapy`, after installing this program on my machine. The version of scapy is: `Welcome to Scapy (2.2.0)`

Well anyway here is the script that does not work for me:

```
sr1(IP(dst="131.215.9.49")/UDP()/DNS(rd=1,qd=DNSQR(qname="www.oreilly.com")))
```

All this does is print:

```
Begin emission:
Finished to send 1 packets. 
.......tons of never ending dots in the shell.............................
..........................................................................
.......................................................................etc
```

How can I fix this script so that it works? I looked up some of the functions and/or methods using `help()` but this did not give me enough info to troubleshoot. I was hoping someone familiar with this would read this for some reason and help me understand this.

Thank-you for reading this.

Happy Holidays,

user_loser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply seems that your packet does not get any answer (which is normal, there is no reason why 131.215.9.49 should answer your recursive queries).

If you want your `sr1()` call to terminate, you can add a `timeout=` argument (value is in seconds).

If you want to make sure 131.215.9.49 is not answering but your `sr1()` call works, you can:

- Issue `host www.oreilly.com 131.215.9.49` from a shell and check you get `;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`.
- Change 131.215.9.49 with the IP address of your DNS server (this one is supposed to answer to your recursive queries) and check you get an answer.

You can also, to understand what is happening, try to run `tcpdump` while running your tests and see whether which packets are sent and/or received.

Comment: What does the syntax look like to add a `timeout` parameter? I looked at the `help(sr1)` and saw some information on this but I am still confused. For instance why are there forward slashes in the script? I am not familiar with the forward slash syntax `/UDP()/DNS()` for instance. Thank-you for answering this I am experimenting with this info now. :D

Comment: I just figured out a way to add a `timeout` argument to `sr1()`. `sr1(IP(dst="131.215.9.49")/UDP()/DNS(rd=1, qd=DNSQR(qname="www.oreilly.com")),timeout=25)` The program quit after 25 seconds and printed `Received 9 packets, got 0 answers, remaining 1 packets` I guess this is a win. :) ^_0

Comment: I ran the `host www.oreilly.com 131.215.9.49` from a bash shell and did receive the `;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached` line :D

Comment: Yes, all your advice worked! Thank-you @Pierre. :D I ran `host www.oreilly.com 8.8.8.8` and received some output and also changed the DNS server to 8.8.8.8 (Google) in the script above and received an actual response I was looking for. The script I used is: `sr1(IP(dst="8.8.8.8")/UDP()/DNS(rd=1, qd=DNSQR(qname="www.oreilly.com")),timeout=45)` I really appreciate the help. You did not have to answer this. Thank-you man/sir XD *awesome-face.jpg*

Comment: Sorry I missed your comments but it seems like you did not need my help in the end ;-).